# Como hacer consultas query sql como mysql pero en SAP ONE R3

Tags: sap

Estoy utilizando SAP R3, soy iniciante en esto pero tengo conocimientos de programación.
He visto que en alguna parte se puede abrir una ventana a traves de una transaccion en SAP donde puedes colocar tu query con las consultas desde SAP mismo, me he percatado que son algo diferentes que el SQL pero similares.

Cómo podría acceder a realizar mi query desde SAP?
Y como se llama el tipo de sql que se maneja en SAP?

He buscado bastante en google, pero como que SAP es gigantesto debo ser específico a la hora de buscarlo.

[image: Mi idea es llegar a esta vista]

Y desde esa vista realizar las consultas que necesito, unir tablas, hacer group by, etc.

Disculpe mi pregunta es muy general y quizas algo incomprensible, pero intento que comprendan mi pregunta.

Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Si estas usando SAP B1 la respuesta a tu primera pregunta sería el Query Manager

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Las consultas SQL varían dependiendo que Base de Datos que utilizas, si usas La BD SQLServer utilizarías el SQL estandar, por otro lado si utilizas HANA como BD, estarías utilizando SQL Script.

Saludos

Comment: Disculpame, no he especificado que es R3. Es esa la que utilizo. Pero justo eso es lo que busco, pero en SAP R3